# My java applet gets access denied to images that it embeds

Tags: java, applet

I am coding a Java chess gui. It runs fine as an applet from Eclipse but I am struggling to get it to work on my local machine from an HTML page. I am using images which I include in the JAR. Images are accessed properly with an Eclipse Debug. What am I missing :( ?

**The HTML looks like :**

```
<html>
<applet code="Ginsie" 
        height="300px" width="300px" archive="chess.jar">
</applet>
</html>
```

**The output of the Java Console (open from the browser) :**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at BoardPanel.loadSquares(BoardPanel.java:105)
    at BoardPanel.<init>(BoardPanel.java:34)
    at Ginsie.<init>(Ginsie.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission ..\img\squares\Wood\BSQUARE.jpg read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.canRead(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at Square.<clinit>(Square.java:47)
    ... 24 more
Exception : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: look at `by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission ..\img\squares\Wood\BSQUARE.jpg read)` line..try using `Run As Administrator` if you are on Windows

Comment: Yes but I am not even sure of where the applet is trying to get the image. I am using ImageIO.read(new File(X)); with X a relative path in Eclipse. Is my applet actually looking into its contents to get my image ? Or is it looking somewhere else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the stack trace, it looks as if you are calling javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(File). In Eclipse, it likely works because it is accessing the local filesystem to read the image. Try using Class.getResourceAsStream() to read the file off the classpath (i.e. from the jar) and then pass the InputStream to javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(InputStream).

Comment: Okay I see the problem now. However, how should I proceed more in details to be able to execute transparently either from Eclipse or from a web page ? i.e. at the moment in my project in Eclipse all classes are in the default package, and I have a folder images adjacent to this location.

Comment: Do I need to add some mappings in the classpath ?

Comment: Your images folder will need to be on the "Java Build Path" in Eclipse. You will also want to make sure that folder is including all files (this is part of the build path configuration). Once that is done, you should be able to read files using something like myClass.getResourceAsStream("/example.png").